# Why can't I change my INT from unsigned to signed? Is signed Zerofill possible?

Tags: mysql, integer, unsigned, signed, zerofill

I have a field called `NUMBER` in a table called `TEST`

```
NUMBER is int(8) Unsigned Zerofill Not Null
```

I need negative numbers in this field now and I'd still like them zerofilled
For example `-00023419`

I can change it to signed, but can't seem to get zerofilled.

if I do: `alter table test modify number int(8) signed zerofill not null` - 
It stays unsigned zerofill

if I do: `alter table test modify number int(8) zerofill not null` - 
  It stays unsigned zerofill

if I do: `alter table test modify number int(8) signed not null` - 
I get signed but no zerofill

When I had it set to signed, I put an a negative number then tried to change to zerofill and the number changed to `00000000` and everything was set to unsigned again.  It it impossible to have signed zerofilled numbers?

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html says:

> If you specify `ZEROFILL` for a numeric column, MySQL automatically adds the `UNSIGNED` attribute to the column.

Reported as a bug in 2006, closed as "Not a Bug".
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24356

---

Re your comment:

> So does this mean no one out there has negative zero filled data in a mysql database?

Right. The most common use case for ZEROFILL is to make sure things like zip codes or bank account numbers use a fixed number of digits. These cases don't support negative values anyway, so why bother with ugly strings like -00001234?

> can you convert it to zerofilled with PHP?

Yes, you can format numbers with zero-padding in PHP.

```
<?php

$n = -1234;
printf("Number is %08d\n", $n);
```

Output:

```
Number is -0001234
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php for more neat formatting things you can do with `printf()`/`sprintf()`.

Comment: So does this mean no one out there has negative zero filled data in a mysql database?  If so, my next question would be,  can you convert it to zerofilled with PHP?   so if my database has -23419  in that field, I'll need to convert it to -00023419 on my webpage.

Answer (score 1):

ZEROFILL implies UNSIGNED.

MySQL Reference Manual  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

> If you specify ZEROFILL for a numeric column, MySQL automatically adds the UNSIGNED attribute to the column.

With all the potential problems, I avoid using the non-standard MySQL `ZEROFILL` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if your column is a foreign key or a primary key, MySQL doesn't allow this modification to happen. You have to do this beforehand.

Comment: not my downvote but anything is possible with a script

Comment: Haha, no worry! I only tried to help since it happened to me once